# Retrieve user info from azureAD profile

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, jsom, azure-ad

Could anyone suggest some way to retrieve user info from AzureAD using **JSOM** or **REST API** only..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure Graph API in the postman tool to get the exact query.

Please read the below steps how to get - steps are originally explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49370311).

Microsoft introduces Graph APIs for fetching user details and roles attached. User Detail API:

https://graph.windows.net//users?api-version=1.6

Authorization:**Access Token**

**Access token** you can generate using resource as https://graph.windows.net/ and authentication endpoint as https://login.microsoftonline.com/.

Note: You must have Microsoft Graph API Permission as well.

Below are some other graph API endpoints:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/directoryroles-operations

Directory roles:

https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryRoles?api-version=1.6

List the users with roles:

https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/directoryRoles/ce8c598b-20eb-42b6-89c6-cf6c184ba416/$links/members?api-version=1.6

Answer (score 0):

You could create SPFx solution to call Graph api to get user profile.

Official tutorial [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial)

```
this.props.context.aadHttpClientFactory
    .getClient('https://graph.microsoft.com')
    .then((client: AadHttpClient) => {
      // Search for the users with givenName, surname, or displayName equal to the searchFor value
      return client
        .get(
          `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,mail,userPrincipalName&$filter=(givenName%20eq%20'${escape(this.state.searchFor)}')%20or%20(surname%20eq%20'${escape(this.state.searchFor)}')%20or%20(displayName%20eq%20'${escape(this.state.searchFor)}')`,
          AadHttpClient.configurations.v1
        );
    })
```

Comment: Can we use graph API in a JSOM based running solution?

Comment: Can't do this yet.